# How to set a permanent environment variable?

Tags: bash, java, environment-variables, tomcat

I am not yet a Linux guy and I have some problem trying to add a new permanent environment variable.

So I have to set a new environment variable named **CATALINA_HOME** with this value: **/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23**

What can I do to set it permanently?

Tnx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the following to the `/etc/profile` file (for system wide change) or to `~/.profile` for local user.

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23
```